# How do you vertically center a radio button within a div that can grow or diminish?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to vertically center this radio button within a div without editing the HTML if possible.

Currently the radio button resides in the upper left corner if an image is present. The text is vertically aligned to the middle by adding a 'vertical-align: middle' to the image. How can I do this with the radio button?

I have a JSFiddle example here I'm working with.

https://jsfiddle.net/blobula/hex4botk/3/

HTML

```
<div class="clearfix" id="ListOptions_ChoiceLine0" iscorrect="">
                <div class="marginRight5 marginBottom5 clsSectionContent pull-left marginLeft10 width20">
                    <i class="fa fa-check ng-hide" ng-show="((IsReview &amp;&amp; drAnswer.DataColumnIsCorrect) || (FeedbackClicked &amp;&amp; UserAnswer.length > 0 &amp;&amp; drAnswer.DataColumnIsCorrect &amp;&amp; drAnswer.DataColumnIsSelected))" aria-label="Correct Answer"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-close ng-hide" ng-show="(IsReview || FeedbackClicked) &amp;&amp; UserAnswer.length > 0 &amp;&amp; !drAnswer.DataColumnIsCorrect &amp;&amp; drAnswer.DataColumnIsSelected" aria-label="Incorrect Answer"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="marginRight10 marginBottom5 clsSectionContent pull-left"><input type="radio" id="Option0" ng-checked="drAnswer.DataColumnIsSelected" ng-disabled="!AssessmentMode" ng-click="ListOptions_RadioBtnClick(this)" name="ListOptionsRadioBtns" value="1"></div>
                <div class="clsSectionContent pull-left width90">
                    <label for="Option0" ng-bind-html="BindHTML(drAnswer.DataColumnAnswerText)" ng-class="{'fontNormal':!(Mode == PlayerModes.PreviewWithFeedback || IsReview || FeedbackClicked)}" class="ng-binding fontNormal"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3c/d7/d9/3cd7d9e37b06574cc51264475ca9c26a.png" alt="ironman" height="" width="100">Ironman</label>

                </div>
            </div>
```

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.width20 {
    width: 20px;
}
.marginBottom5 {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.marginRight5 {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.clsSectionContent {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.marginLeft10 {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.pull-left {
    float: left!important;
}
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: inline-block;
}

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    margin: 4px 0 0;
    margin-top: 1px\9;
    line-height: normal;
}
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
}
.width90 {
    width: 90%;
}

.fontNormal {
    font-weight: normal;
}


Any help would be appreciated.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using flexbox. You need to apply a simple style sheet on the `ListOptions_ChoiceLine0` element.

**HTML**

```
<div class="clearfix verticallyCenter" id="ListOptions_ChoiceLine0" iscorrect="">
```

**CSS**

```
.verticallyCenter {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}
```

Updated link: https://jsfiddle.net/bvLyj0xe/1/